# infer hourly time series from unevenly spaced intervals

Tags: python, time-series, interpolation

I have a dataframe

| Value | Interval |
| --- | --- |
| 0.32 | 2.56 |
| 0.46 | 4.43 |
| 2.43 | 10.12 |

Where `interval` means how many hours have passed from the trial start. I want to infer hourly values. What is the wisest way to do so given that I do not have specific "date_time" variable. Maybe some form of linear regression? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a simple linear regression of your data you can use to extract what you are after. The value based of your description is dependent on  some amount of time passing, so that is the x axis, and the "Value" the y axis.

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
# Included to show visually
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


# Your data mapped as a list
x = [2.56, 4.43, 10.12]
y = [0.32, 0.46, 2.43]

# Linear regression object
linear_regressor = LinearRegression() 

# Reshape your list into a matrix using numpy. This makes [1, 2, 3] become [[1], [2], [3]
X = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)

# Create your model of x to y.
linear_regressor.fit(X, y) 

# Predict values for some hours here
for i in range(5, 11):
    # Using the predict function here you can capture an array of hours, 
    #but for demo purposes I am prining each prediction
    print("At interval {hour}, the predicted value is {value}".format(
        hour=i,
        value=linear_regressor.predict(np.array(i).reshape(1, -1))
    ))

# Visual demo of your model :)
y_prediction = linear_regressor.predict(X)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_prediction, color='red')
plt.show()
```

I hope this helps you. Just once you have used the `fit()` method, use your linear regression models `predict()` method to pull out hourly intervals. I'd recommend you have a little more data to produce accurate results aswell. Good luck!